# Weak Convergence of finite Borel measures on $[0, 1]$

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $\mu_{n}$ is a sequence of finite Borel measures so that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{n}([a, b]) = \mu([a, b])$ for any subinterval $a< b$. I know that for any continuous function we have that

$$\int f d\mu_{n} \to \int f d\mu. $$

My question is: Can we strengthen this to every bounded measurable function on $[0, 1]$? My thought is yes, since we can use compactness of $[0, 1]$ to show that every finite Borel measure is regular, and then use regularity, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Are you sure that the assumption should be $\mu_n([a, b]) = \mu([a, b])$?

Comment: Ah, it might be that $\mu_{n}([a, b]) \to \mu([a, b])$, but I can't recall, I saw this problem earlier today and I'm not $100$% sure what it should be.

Comment: Are these positive measures, or signed or complex measures?

Comment: @DanielFischer does it make a difference?

Comment: Only in how badly it can fail. With signed measures, you can't even deduce $\int f\,d\mu_n \to \int f \,d\mu$ for continuous $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $\mu_n = \varepsilon_{\frac{1}{n}},$ the measure that assigns total mass 1 to the point $\frac{1}{n},$ and, similarly, $\mu = \varepsilon_0.$ Then $\mu_n \to \mu$ in the sense you described, yet $\mu_n \left( \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, 0]} \right) = 0,$ whilst $\mu\left( \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, 0]} \right) = 1.$